# Running PHP script from other directory

Tags: php

I have a PHP script of about 10 .php files under the same directory. i.e.

```html
www.domain.com/script_directory/
```

I wanted to run that script from another director and tried the following:

```html
www.domain.com/some_directory/index.php
```

where index.php contains

```html
<?php
include "../script_directory/index.php";
?>
```

Of course the above doesn't work.
Is there any way to set the working path of the script in PHP, similar to "HTML base Tag"?
Some files of the script are "called" via ajax and the others with direct links.

Comment: What directory are you in when you want to include the index file? If it's some_directory then I don't see why the code you wrote would not work

Comment: include "script_directory/index.php";

Comment: `__DIR__` will always contain the full path that the current file is in (regardless of how its included/called)

Comment: I already did that (include "script_directory/index.php") and it doesn't work. When index.php links to somefile.php under script_directory then you are transferred from www.domain.com/some_directory/ to www.domain.com/script_directory/. I want user to always stay at www.domain.com/some_directory.

Comment: If your `index.php` is in `site_directory` then if you do `include __DIR__."/../script_directory/script_to_include.php"` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I want user to always stay at www.domain.com/some_directory

To do it, you can put a HTTP redirect in the index.php at the root, something like this:

```
<?php
header("location:/some_directory");
```

If using Apache, you can do it using .htaccess like this:

```
Redirect / http://www.example.com/some_directory
```

But all depends on the rules/behaviour that you want.  Using include in PHP only insert a script into it, allowing to use the code/functions/classes that are into it.